# React global counter variable updated out of context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

(create-react-app) React 17.0.1, TS 4.0.3

```
// utils/createUniqueModalId.ts

let counter = 0;

export const createUniqueModalId = (): string => {
  return `modal-${++counter}`;
};
```

```
// hooks/useModal.ts

import { createUniqueModalId } from 'src/utils/createUniqueModalId';
import { useRef } from 'react';

export type TUseModalData = {
  id: string;
};

export const useModal = (): TUseModalData => {
  const modalId = useRef<string>(createUniqueModalId());
  
  console.log({ modalId: modalId.current });

  return { id: modalId.current };
};
```

I got 4 modals and in the dev version of my app, `console.log` returns me: `modal-1, modal-3, modal-5, modal-7`.

But after production build it works good: `modal-1, modal-2, modal-3, modal-4`.
I don't understand what happened here.

Is it a webpack issue or is this the expected behaviour of a TS/React app? If not, how to take control over this or fix?

Comment: Might be related to some debug tools creating more instances (no idea how react does this). You could trace them by adding `console.trace()` to your `createUniqueModalId` function and checking the call stacks where the additional calls come from.

Comment: @Mr.Manhattan it looks like every component call this method two times BUT I used console.trace and console.log in same place. In browser console I see one console.log per two console.traces

Answer (score 0):

Additional renders are possible in dev. Because `createUniqueModalId` gets called on every render, counter is being incremented each time. I would use `useMemo` in this case:

```
const modalId = useMemo<string>(() => createUniqueModalId(), []);
```

Comment: I used useMemo before but it doesn't help.

Comment: Oh, I see. It looks like this is due to HMR https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/